# character error when uploading high size file

Tags: mysql

I have a large .sql file and when I try to upload it I get an error like this

```
mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 db_name < file.sql
```

The error i got;

```
ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'SQLite format 3'.
```

I also tried different installation attempts but without success.

```
mysql -hlocalhost -r -uroot -p --binary-mode -o db_name < file.sql
```

```
mysqldump -p -u root db_name --hex-blob > file.sql
```

Comment: In UTF-16 such a NUL byte `'\0'` happens for basic ASCII characters. So check the SQL encoding.

Comment: @JoopEggen Do I need to convert sql encoding to utf-16?

Comment: If my guess is right your SQL is in the wrong encoding, not UTF-8 but UTF-16. As this can be little endian or big endian, you need to check in an encoding aware editor